# How is market making not considered manipulation?

Tags: regulation

When  I buy a stock I don't actually buy anything. My broker gives money to Goldman Sachs which gives a share at an arbitrary price. And they collect a profit on the difference between the price for the person who gave them a share and what they charged me.

Why is this any different from market manipulation?

Is manipulation ok as long as it is within the bid ask spread?

Comment: You can't manipulate something that wouldn't have existed without you?

Comment: So basically wash trading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My broker gives money to Goldman Sachs which gives a share at an arbitrary price.

If you're dealing with US stocks, [Regulation National Market System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulation_NMS) prevents brokers from giving you a [price that is worse than the national best bid and offer](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/17/242.611).

As noted by a blog post on [kalzumeus.com](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2019/6/26/how-brokerages-make-money/),

> Payment for order flow is a minor footnote to the story of discount
>   brokerages, in the same fashion that HFT is basically irrelevant to
>   retail traders except for decreasing their cost of trading by
>   decimating spreads.
>
> Schwab earned 1.4% of revenue from payment for order flow, TD
>   Ameritrade about 8.4%, and E*TRADE about 6.1%.
>
> Interactive Brokers has historically been quite reticent about
>   participating in internalization, because it doesn’t play well with
>   their sophisticated clients; they earn about 1.1% from it.

Comment: What percentage of revenue does Goldman Sachs get from manipulation

Comment: You can look at their 10K: https://www.goldmansachs.com/investor-relations/financials/current/10k/2018-10-k.pdf . It looks like they make around 25% of revenues from market making. Perhaps a small fraction of that comes from manipulative behavior but they certainly wouldn't disclose that and any large resulting profits would go under scrutiny.

Comment: If you include ipo underwriting, trading, and other forms I bet it would be near 50%

Comment: Perhaps you can argue all these activities have little societal value but arguing that it is manipulation is a harder sell.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the only way they can  profit on trading (since they suck at their stock predictions) is manipulation, and IPOs usually underperform because of the salesmanship of the bank